# Why does Windows 11 keep resetting my Blue Yeti microphone volume to 50%?

Tags: audio, windows-11, microphone

Like the title states, Windows 11 keeps resetting my Blue Yeti mic input volume to 50%. This happens when I reboot or sleep the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Make sure the Speakers playback device for your Blue Yeti is disabled.
> This is the playback option for playing through a device you plug into
> the mic's 3.5mm jack. In my use case, I have
> headphones and don't require this jack. I had recently enabled the
> device which looks like it was resetting my mic volume to 50%...no
> idea why this fixed it but it did for me at least.

Taken from https://blog.keitharm.me/windows-11-keeps-res/, which is down. [Google Cache Mirror](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:t7oUdnMFvYkJ:blog.keitharm.me/windows-11-keeps-res/).

Comment: Had this exact issue and it worked perfectly. Is there any way we can get this as the accepted answer to help others with this issue.

Comment: Done. There is a delay in being to able to accept your own answers and I forgot to come back and accept it, so thanks for the reminder.